# Difference of div width in Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

In safari the background of my menu navigation drop-down menu's is much wider than in Chrome/Firefox. I don't see there to be any css attribute of that width to explain why the different is happening.

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1g4YBhT

Chrome

[image]

Safari

[image]

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1g4YBhT

CSS

```
#fixed #menu ul.level1 div {position:absolute; left:-9999px; z-index: 3000; background-color: #53CDD7; }
#fixed #menu ul.level1 div ul { width: 100%; }

#fixed #menu ul.level1 li:hover div { left: 0; top:44px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
#fixed #menu ul.level1 li:hover div ul {display:block; position:relative; }

#fixed #menu ul.level1 li div ul { line-height: 22px; }
#fixed #menu ul.level1 li div ul li a { background: transparent url("../Images/Menu/arrow.png") 5px 2px no-repeat; font-family: 'blissregular'; font-weight: normal; /* margin: 0 10px 0 10px; */ padding: 0 0 0 15px; margin-left: -20px; }
#fixed #menu ul.level1 li div ul li a:hover { color: #00ADEF; }

#fixed #menu ul.level1 li div ul.level2 li { height: 14px; background: none; text-align: center; display: inline; list-style-type: none; line-height: 16px; float: left; margin: 11px 0 0 0; padding: 0 25px 0 25px; position:relative; border-right: none; text-align: left; width: 100%; }

#fixed #menu ul.level1 li div ul.level2 li a { text-transform: lowercase; }
#fixed #menu ul.level1 li div ul.level2 li a:hover { color: #504F4B !important; text-transform: lowercase; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Safari (Windows), I found that removing `white-space: nowrap;` from `#fixed #menu ul` fixed the issue for me. See line 343 of your global-en.css stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.selector { (;property: value;); } 
.selector { [;property: value;]; }
```

and declare the width of your background for safari only so it same width like in chrome and firefox.